# Can't use -interactive-print to print timestamps after each line in ghci

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm trying to print the current time after each line evaluated in `ghci`. Here's my code so far:

```
module TimePrint (timePrint) where

import System.IO
import Data.Time

getTime :: IO String
getTime = do
    now <- getCurrentTime
    return (formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%T" now)

timePrint :: Show a => a -> IO ()
timePrint a = putStrLn $ show a ++ "\n" ++ getTime
```

And I'm running `ghci` like so: `ghci -interactive-print=TimePrint.timePrint TimePrint`

The error I'm getting is this:

```
TimePrint.hs:12:44:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘IO String’
    In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘getTime’
    In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘"\n" ++ getTime’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I gather it has something to do with the fact that timePrint isn't in the IO monad, but other than that I have no clue. Any ideas? I'd like each line of `ghci` output to look something like:

```
Prelude> 1+2
3
11:59:20
Prelude> 3+4
7
12:00:16
```

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
timePrint a = do
   s <- getTime
   putStrLn $ show a ++ "\n" ++ s
```

`++` wants a string, not an IO action.

Comment: In other words, <- is to run the IO action, and turn it into (in this case) a String?

Comment: @masterchefsenior exactly!